# An interesting equality about Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Consider the square Vanderomode matrix being defined by
\begin{equation}
V = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \\
\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\
x_1^{n-1} & x_2^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The determinant of $V$ can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{det}(V)=\prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq n}\left(x_{j}-x_{i}\right).
\end{equation}
Therefore, if the numbers $x_1,x_2, \cdots,x_n$ ar distinct, then $V$ is invertible, and the final column of $V^{-1}$ can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
y = \begin{bmatrix}
\prod_{q \neq 1} \frac{1}{x_1 - x_q} & 
\prod_{q \neq 2} \frac{1}{x_2 - x_q} & 
\cdots & 
\prod_{q \neq n} \frac{1}{x_n - x_q} 
\end{bmatrix}^\top.
\end{equation}

Now consider the general Vandermonde-like matrix
\begin{equation}
R = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \\
\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\
x_1^{n-1} & x_2^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1}\\
x_1^{n} & x_2^{n} & \cdots & x_n^{n} \\
x_1^{n+1} & x_2^{n+1} & \cdots & x_n^{n+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\
x_1^{2n-1} & x_2^{2n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{2n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $V$ is the sub-matrix composed of the first $n$ rows of $R$.

**Now I have got this equality below, but I’m not sure how to derive it.**
\begin{equation}
Ry = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \\
\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\
x_1^{n-1} & x_2^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1}\\
x_1^{n} & x_2^{n} & \cdots & x_n^{n} \\
x_1^{n+1} & x_2^{n+1} & \cdots & x_n^{n+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\
x_1^{2n-1} & x_2^{2n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{2n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\prod_{q \neq 1} \frac{1}{x_1 - x_q} \\
\prod_{q \neq 2} \frac{1}{x_2 - x_q} \\
\dots \\
\prod_{q \neq n} \frac{1}{x_n - x_q} 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\
\sum_{p=1}^n x_p^n 
\prod_{q \neq p} \frac{1}{x_p - x_q} \\
\sum_{p=1}^n x_p^{n+1} 
\prod_{q \neq p} \frac{1}{x_p - x_q} \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{p=1}^n x_p^{2n-1}
\prod_{q \neq p} \frac{1}{x_p - x_q} 
\end{bmatrix} =
\underbrace{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\
\sum_{p} x_p \\
\sum_{1\leq p_1 \leq p_2 \leq n} x_{p_1}x_{p_2} \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{1\leq p_1 \leq p_2 \leq \cdots \leq p_n \leq n} x_{p_1}x_{p_2}\cdots x_{p_n}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{b}.
\end{equation}

Comment: I suspect that this result is related to [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will study it carefully later.